# Firmware stops execution on function call

Tags: avr, c

I've been experiencing this weird behavior on an AVR ATmega328p.

What is happening is the following: I have written a firmware that makes use of USART, TIMER0 and interrupts. The firmware works as expected.

Here is the output from the USART when it behaves as expected:

```
USART
Timer0
Sched
IRQ
 tick
 tick
 tick
```

But as soon as I add a call to a function (namely Uptime_Create()) to its main(), execution stops at the call of Uptime_Create(). I assume that because I have calls to USART_Puts() after each component is initialized.

This is my main.c

```
/* Written for Rainbowduino (ATmega328p at 16MHz) */

#include "USART.h"
#include "Timer.h"
#include "Sched.h"
#include "Uptime.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

static USART uart;

static void uart_init(const uint32_t baud)
{
    uart = USART_Create(&UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UBRR0L, &UBRR0H, &UDR0);
    USART_SetBaudRate(uart, 38400, F_CPU);
    USART_Enable(uart, 1);
    USART_Puts(uart, "USART\r\n");
}

static void timer_init(void)
{
    Timer t0;
    t0 = Timer_Create(0, &TCCR0A, &TCCR0B,
                &TCNT0, 0,
                &OCR0A, 0,
                &OCR0B, 0,
                0, 0,
                &TIMSK0, &TIFR0);
    Timer_SetOverflowInterrupt(t0, 1);
    Timer_SetClockSource(t0, 3); /* 64 */
    USART_Puts(uart, "Timer0\r\n");
}

static void testTask(void)
{
#if 0
    char utstr[9];
    Uptime_Tick();
    Uptime_ToStr(utstr);
    USART_Puts(uart, utstr);
#endif
    USART_Puts(uart, " tick\r\n");
}

static void sched_init(void)
{
    Sched_Create();
    Sched_AddTask(testTask, 1000, 0);
    USART_Puts(uart, "Sched\r\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    uart_init(38400);
    timer_init();
    //Uptime_Create();
    sched_init();
    sei();
    USART_Puts(uart, "IRQ\r\n");
    while (1)
        Sched_Dispatch();
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    Sched_Update();
}
```

The complete source code is available at github (http://github.com/lazlo/). The main.c was taken from the "lzoOS-test-firmware" repository from the sched/ directory.

In order to build the main.c you will have to check out the "Drivers" and the "lzoOS" repository as well and place them in the same directory.

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
git clone https://github.com/lazlo/Drivers.git
git clone https://github.com/lazlo/lzoOS.git
git clone https://github.com/lazlo/lzoOS-test-firmware.git
cd lzoOS-test-firmware/sched
make
```

As soon as the call to Uptime_Create() is active again, the firmware stops execution (IMHO) after "Timer0" is printed out by USART_Puts().

I have already compiled a version with and without the call to Uptime_Create() and compared the assembly listing (.lss files). From what I can see only offsets differ (as Uptime.o is always linked to the firmware, no matter if the call is made or not).

What Uptime_Create() actually does is to initlaize a static struct (inside of Uptime.c) with zero.

Here is the code form Uptime.c

```
typedef struct UptimeStruct
{
    uint8_t seconds;
    uint8_t minutes;
    uint8_t hours;
} UptimeStruct;

static UptimeStruct uptime;

void Uptime_Create(void)
{
    uptime.seconds = 0;
    uptime.minutes = 0;
    uptime.hours = 0;
}
```

Any suggestions welcome!

UPDATE: I made a little experiment where I only use the USART and Uptime code. It looks like this:

```
#include "USART.h"
#include "Uptime.h"
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{
    USART u;

    u = USART_Create(&UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UBRR0L, &UBRR0H, &UDR0);
    USART_SetBaudRate(u, 38400, F_CPU);
    USART_Enable(u, 1);
    USART_Puts(u, "USART\r\n");

    Uptime_Create();
    USART_Puts(u, "Uptime\r\n");

    while (1)
        ;
}
```

Turns out, the strinf "Uptime" is never printed. Again I looked at the assembly listing but wasn't able to make sense or see the problem that would make the controller halt. What happens in Uptime_Create() looks like this:

```
00000384 <Uptime_Create>:

static UptimeStruct uptime;

void Uptime_Create(void)
{
    uptime.seconds = 0;
 384:   10 92 18 01     sts 0x0118, r1
    uptime.minutes = 0;
 388:   10 92 19 01     sts 0x0119, r1
    uptime.hours = 0;
 38c:   10 92 1a 01     sts 0x011A, r1
 390:   08 95           ret

00000392 <Uptime_Destroy>:
}
```

**UPDATE**: When I was asked to answer if Uptime_Create() ever actually returns (on the microcontroller) I wrote a new minimal firmware that only uses the USART and Uptime module. While running this firmware in Simulavr, I noticed, Uptime_Create() returns but USART_Puts() makes code execution stop/run an endless loop. Specifically it is BitIsSet() in USART_Putc() that checks if UDRE (USART Data Register Empty) bit is set. Weird enough, before I call Uptime_Create() I call USART_Puts(uart, "USART ready\r\n"); which works and I can see the output. But after calling Uptime_Create() the next call to USART_Puts() results in an endless loop because the UDRE in the UCSRA (USART control and status register) is never set.

Why this is, I can only guess. As i tried to set a data watchpoint using gdb in the simulator but as it seems the simulator does not support data watchpoints.

**UPDATE**: I found the reason: Uptime_Create() initializes "static UptimeStruct uptime" zero, which turns out to be at the same memory address as "static USARTStruct usart[0]". Which in turn results in setting the pointers in usart struct that point to the registers (UCSR[A..C] and so on) to zero.

Comment: You need to include the called functions in the question itself.  Without that this will probably be closed as unanswerable.

Comment: makefile:41: ../CppUTest/build/MakefileWorker.mk: No such file or directory

Comment: @BruceAbbott: You used the CppUTest from the debian package. That one is missing the MakefileWorker.mk : ( Try the cpputest git repository from github. That one should work

Comment: @ChrisStratton Added the code from Uptime.c

Comment: Try using a debugger to step through the execution... My guess is you are having a hardfault somewhere in that create line.
Have you tried using a debugger and breakpoints to find out what line of code in USART_CREATE is causing the lockup?

Comment: @gregb212 No, I haven't yet. I'm not sure if I can do on-chip debugging with the programmer (USBasp) I have. IMHO you need JTAG to do that on the AVR.

Sure you mean USART_Create() and not Uptime_Create()?

Aside: I only know hardfaults from the ARM, but haven't seen anything like that on AVR. But maybe I just don't comprehend and you are talking about the equivalent of a hardfault on an AVR.

Comment: You could be right. I am not as familiar with AVR. Probably a more correct statement would be you are either accessing an incorrect address or jumping to one. If you lack a debugger, you can always use the ancient pin toggle method. Toggle a pin high, line by line, and see where it stops toggling.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but does your Uptime Create function actually return?

Comment: Good question. The answer is a bit more complex.

I have unit tests for the Uptime code. I've written that code on my computer and the unit tests would not work if Uptime_Create() would never return.

But on the micro-controller I can't really say. I will write a small main that will only initialize the USART, call Uptime_Create() and then call USART_Puts() to verify Uptime_Create() returned.

Comment: That could be related to memory aligment as you are accessing 24 bits structure. I believe this mcu needs a 16 bits alignment.Try making it 32 bit or declare the struct instance with a keyword like __ALIGNED__  (with gcc)

Comment: @Pier-YvesLessard No.  This is an 8-bit processor.  Also even on something that did have alignment requirements, the code in question would not trigger issues with them.

Comment: -1 because the code **that is key to answering the question** was not included in the posting even after explicit request.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that `USARTStruct` and `UptimeStruct` are overlapping in memory, so when `Uptime_Create()` initializes the time it wipes out part of `USARTStruct` and the UART transmit code gets stuck waiting on the wrong register.

In `USART.c` you have this:-

```
typedef struct USARTStruct
{
    volatile uint8_t *ucsra;
    volatile uint8_t *ucsrb;
    volatile uint8_t *ucsrc;
    volatile uint8_t *ubrrl;
    volatile uint8_t *ubrrh;
    volatile uint8_t *udr;
} USARTStruct;

static USARTStruct usart[0];
```

`usart[0]` is an array of size zero. Change it to `static struct USARTStruct usart[1]` and the compiler should allocate sufficient space for the structure.

Comment: This is why questions **must include the code**, digging around in the asker's github to find a mistake like this should not be required.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: You are right! This was my 2nd question, so I guess there is chance to improve.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Damn! You are right! I just found out that addresses of uptime and usart overlap. But I didn't get to the point where I noticed usart to be of length 0! Thank you sooo much!

Comment: @lazlo Of course, *what you hope to accomplish* by mocking up the USART register structure in RAM remains unclear.  To actually access a USART, you need to use the physical addresses of these registers.  If you want a struct that reflects those, this is not that.